Android cellphone multiple profiles issue
I have two Gmail accounts on my cellphone. Is there any way to force all apps onto one account other than uninstall and reinstall everything? Android shows all (or nearly all) apps under both accounts. Especially the few beta apps?

Welcome. While everyone is free to have their opinions and critics of anything, Stack Exchange is strictly a Q&A site, not a place to rant. I've removed the second point because it's not a question.

The Google account system on Android is not app specific. Thus no matter in which app you log-in the account itself will be stored in the central system-wide account system used by all Google apps. Therefore all apps are automatically logged-in with all accounts in this account system.

Thanks. But my one account shows 79 apps and the other account shows 78. Not to mention Google photos and Gmail seem to throw me or induce me back and forth between the accounts even though yes I can manually change them I have to notice the icon has changed. Thanks for trying though!
